# how i can push notification from laravel api to react native app?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, react-native, push-notification

I am trying to send a push notification from web app using laravel api to react native app  so is there a way to do it ?

i am using Laravel for web app and react native for mobile app

Comment: pusher, laravel echo etc

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a Reac Native application, simple websockets will not be sufficient to receive notification on the mobile application. For that you need a platform or service, since doing it from 0 is quite difficult. I would recommend using [Pusher Beams](https://pusher.com/beams) to start. And in combination with the [pusher-push-notifications](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications) package you can send notifications from Laravel to Android iOS without any problem.

[Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) is another platform that can serve you in the process. In combination with [this package](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm) you will also find it easy to implement server-side with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `laravel-websockets` that acts as a pusher replacement for backend notification broadcasting. Then you can listen to the designated channels on the front end using `laravel echo`.

Laravel websockets: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets

Laravel echo: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo